# Debugger fail with fresh UWP C++ solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, uwp

I have installed Visual Studio twice to attempt to fix this.

Process:

1) new solution for C++ UWP.
2) add a button and an event handler
        to mainpage.xaml.

3) include a line of code in the event handler
        (int dum=0;)

4) set a breakpoint for the line of code.
5) run in debug mode.

Hitting the button on the page has no effect.  Hover over the breakpoint and the following message is displayed "The breakpoint will not be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document."

There are no modules loaded.  I tried to add the project's .pdb file to the Tools->Options->Debug->Symbols and that had no effect.

There are no modules loaded in the modules tab.

I have the same problem with two other solutions -- one of which is my working solution.  This is a work-stopping problem.

Other ideas?

Comment: Look on the "modules" tab (you may need to display it) to see why the PDB wasn't loaded.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm thank you for the reminder.  I have edited the post to note that there are no modules loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Set the debugger type to native.